# Attribute Table Sort Disordered in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, sorting

I am using QGIS.  I opened my attribute table in Open Office Calc and sorted the table by a column.  I believe I had all the columns selected when I sorted.  Now when viewing the layer, everything is screwed up with wrong attributes.

Is it not a good idea to sort the table?

Is there a way to revert back?

Comment: In shapefile the first geometry that is stored to the .shp part is connected with the first row of the .dbf part, second feature with the secod row and so on. Sorting the .dbf with an external program is definitely a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you opened a .dbf belonging to a shapefile?  Opening such a table with another program than gis-software can screw up your file!

If you do not have a backup, I fear your data is lost ...